# Set background color to transparent but doesn't work. Use EasyLoading package

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

When I set the background color to transparent in [EasyLoading](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_easyloading), it doesn't show the transparent effect, but a black color.
I tried to figure out in source code but get nothing.
I wonder that if there an anyway to make the background color transparent, so it can show everything behind.

**Update**
Solved in this issue:
https://github.com/0xPool/flutter_easyloading/issues/135

```
void showLoading([String loadingText = 'Loading']) {
  EasyLoading.instance
    ..loadingStyle = EasyLoadingStyle.custom
    ..indicatorType = EasyLoadingIndicatorType.ring
    ..indicatorColor = Colors.transparent
    ..backgroundColor = Colors.transparent
    ..textColor = Colors.transparent
    ..textStyle =
        TextStyle(color: _loadingText, fontSize: 14.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Helvetica')
    ..textPadding = EdgeInsets.zero
    ..indicatorWidget = Column(
      children: [
        _LoadingRing(
          color: _loadingRingGradient,
        ),
        addVerticalSpace(32)
      ],
    );

  EasyLoading.show(status: loadingText, maskType: EasyLoadingMaskType.none, dismissOnTap: true);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you look in issues section of the EasyLoading in GitHub? If this is a common issue, there might be something present there which can help you.

Comment: I didn't figure out to find solutions in its issue section at the first moment. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `BoxShadow` at your code `..boxShadow = <BoxShadow>[]`. Please find out issue related this at below link.

[EasyLoading GitHub Open Issue](https://github.com/0xPool/flutter_easyloading/issues/135)

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm trying to use custom widget for loading but it is still showing black background wrapping my widget.

Comment: yes. check my comment on the github issue
https://github.com/nslogx/flutter_easyloading/issues/135#issuecomment-1275991923